# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0” error in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm sending data through *ajax* request and after processing the data an array is returned, which is encoded to *json* format.

```
$response = array(
            'data' => $leaveData,
            'message' => 'Event added successfully',
            'status' => 'success'
        );
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

where `$leaveData` is an associative array:

```
   Array
(
    [id] => 131
    [user_id] => 134
    [leave_type_id] => 2
    [issued_date] => 2017-10-17
    [leave_from] => 2017-10-25
    [leave_to] => 2017-10-26
    [leave_description] => test
    [leave_status] => 1
)
```

Here's my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
url:"leave/request",
data:{
  id:eventID,
  user_id:empID,
  leave_type:leaveType,
},
  type:"POST",
  cache:false,
  success: function (data, resp){
    var json = data, 
    obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
  }
});
```

Also, I think `JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json)` are used for the same purpose?

I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: console.log(json) and post what the json you receive is

Comment: The error suggests that the output of your php script is xml / html. What is the exact response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (core_request_calendar.js:379)
    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3101)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3213)
    at done (jquery-1.10.2.js:9312)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.10.2.js:9722)

Comment: this is the actual error.. sorry it all went messy

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` return?

Comment: @user2887596 I tried var json = data,
                                                obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
                                                console.log(json);
                                                return;
but only the error showed up

Comment: the console.log isn't executed since the error occurs before it. put it as the first statement in the success function

Comment: haha.. whole HTML document is being outputted instead of JSON....??

Comment: that error usually happened if the return is html not json, try the console.log before the var declaration

Comment: yes tried... the output is html... but how? :/

Comment: most likely there is an error in your php code which make that request not returning the json output. Can you see any error message in the html response? if you use chrome you can go to the network tab in the dev tool to preview the response of the leave/request

Comment: what does the HTML say? is it an PHP error message? Or a Server error?

Comment: it is just HTML... page source code of the page... no errors found

Comment: network tab>preview>shows "failed to load response data"

Comment: I tried adding header('Content-type: application/json'); before encoding to json.. and also I added dataType:'JSON'.. now it is hitting error callback

Comment: are you even looking at the console output when calling console.log() ?

Comment: @Woncker yes I'm. And like I said.. nothing more than whole HTML source code

Comment: then your php output is broken. would be helpful to have a look at the php source code

Comment: @Azima Is your problem solved ? Feel free to accept the best answer to close topic thks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem just a few while ago and the problem lies within the data I was trying to pull into success callback, I just removed the static variables and such that I was trying to get into the json and kept the its values strictly coming only from the query results. Maybe it's the same for you.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the ajax `dataType` property to interprate JSON directly after ajax response like :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"leave/request",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
        id:eventID,
        user_id:empID,
        leave_type:leaveType,
    },
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Azima Instead of downvote, it's better to say why it's not solving your trouble, and what would you prefer as answer

Answer (score -1):

Add an "error" callback to your ajax function, and then print the content:

```
  error: function(data) {
      console.log("AJAX ERROR:", data);
  }
```

This will show you what ajax is trying to parse as json.

Comment: The error occurs in the `success` function when trying to parse the data so there is no ajax error.

Comment: yes... I have that error callback function, and it is not being hit.. error occurs in the success function

Comment: If you add datatype:'json', the parse of response is automatic, and the error callback will do the work.
Anyway, you can print the response and check if it's a valid json string. Else you have found the problem. You have only these ways to solve.
And... I don't know why haters must vote as negative the solution, stupid persons :\